# GWT NumberFormat problems with high precision decimals

Tags: gwt, string-formatting, number-formatting

I'm using GWT 2.0 and when I try to use NumberFormat to format a Double the results are not as expected:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getFormat( "#.########" );
Double d = new Double("0.256281093911");
format.format(d);
```

formatted string: 0.02147484

As you can see the formatted value is wrong (this can be seen in the gwt showcase). Is this something related to the custom format I'm using (#.########)? or is this a bug in the GWT formatter? 
If this is a bug, have someone found a workaround?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `Double d = 0.256281093911D;`. It can help you find if it's a string to double problem, or just the formatting.

Comment: I tried it, but still the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

[link text](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/NumberFormat.html#getFormat%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)
you might try NumberFormat.getDecimalFormat. Also, it might have something to do with your browser's locale and/or it's decimal delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

A Double is stored in binary format in java in general. Working with binary float values is in most cases not what you want - conversion between binary and decimal floats causes rounding errors.

Try "BigDecimal", which stores float values in DECIMAL format, not in binary format.

Sample code:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getFormat("#.########");
format.format(new BigDecimal("0.256281093911"));
```